# Powershell File database comparison with drive letter variable input

Tags: database, file, powershell, variables, scanning

I'm building a tool that will scan my files and a friend's files. We will use this to make sure we have the same files in our databases. The script I have so far has a variable input issue. For some reason, the PowerShell script fails on my drive letter input. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is my script:

```
{
    function Show-Menu {
        param (
            [string] $Title  = "Andy's Manual Database Tool"
        )

        Clear-Host
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host -f Green "1. Andys Files listing"
        Write-Host -f green "2. Reids files listing"
        Write-Host -f Red "3. Dark Matter Testing"
        Write-Host "4. Convert .txt to .csv"
        Write-Host "5. Convert Blank File to .csv"
        Write-Host "6. Convert .csv to .txt"
    }

    Function Body {
        Show-Menu

        Write-Host ""

        $Input = Read-Host "Please make a selection"

        if ($Input -eq "1") {
            Clear-Host

            $root = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify the location of Database? Example format: C:\*'
            $y = read-host -Prompt 'Input file types. Format Example: " .jpg,.mp4,.mp3,.pdf .... " Do * for all'
            $z = Read-Host -Prompt 'Your Save file name will be? Examples: Movies database , Music database , audiobooks.' 
            Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File -Recurse *.$y  | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $z Andy.csv
        }

        if ($Input -eq "2") {
            Clear-Host

            $root = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify the location of Database? Example format: C:\*'
            $y = read-host -Prompt 'Input file types. File Format Examples: " .jpg,.mp4,.mp3,.pdf .... " Do * for all'
            $z = Read-Host -Prompt 'Your Save file name will be? Examples: Movies database , Music database , audiobooks.' 
            Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File -Recurse *.$y  | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $z' From Reid.csv'
        }

        if ($Input -eq "3") { Get-Process | Stop-Process }

        if ($Input -eq "4") {
            Clear-Host
            Get-ChildItem *.txt  | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace ".txt",".csv" }
        }

        if ($Input -eq "5") {
            Clear-Host 
            Get-ChildItem * -Exclude *.ps1,*.CSV,*.TXT | rename-item -newname {  "$($_.name).CSV" }
        }

        if ($Input -eq "6") {
            Clear-Host
            Get-ChildItem *.csv  | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace ".csv",".txt" }
        }

        Write-Host  'Complete! ^_^'

        Start-Sleep -seconds 5

        Body
    }
    Body
}
```

This issue is here, from the script above:

```
$root = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify the location of Database? Example format: C:\*'
$y = read-host -Prompt 'Input file types. Format Example: " .jpg,.mp4,.mp3,.pdf .... " Do * for all'
$z = Read-Host -Prompt 'Your Save file name will be? Examples: Movies database , Music database , audiobooks.' 
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File -Recurse *.$y  |
  Select-Object -Property Name |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $z Andy.csv
```

I'm using `$root` as an input for my drive letter or location path which is the problem.

Comment: What are you typing in?

Comment: With proper formatting, immediately noticed your issue.  Never use automatic variables as your variable names.  In this case: `$Input`

Comment: Hi Jacob Colvin, Im inputting the drive letter.  So it could be c:\ or c:\temp\ or d , g or f:\

Comment: @rogerwilcolta The code you said was "the problem" worked fine for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few minor issues.

1. `$z Andy.csv` Needs to be changed to `"$z Andy.csv"`. You will notice when you ran this before you would of received the following message:

> Export-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value
>   "Andy.csv" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one
>   character long."

2. `Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File -Recurse *.$y` Needs to be changed to `Get-ChildItem -Path "$root" -Recurse -Include "*$y"` - You are prompting the user to put in file extension with `.<extension>` (assigned to `$y`) then you are trying to filter with `$y`

   Ex:`$y = read-host -Prompt 'Input file types. Format Example: " .jpg,.mp4,.mp3,.pdf .... " Do * for all'`

   Issue: `"*.$y"` this would equal "..extension". Your results would then be 0 (unless you had a file with `..jpg` or something like that)

Corrected:

```
if ($Input -eq "1") {
            Clear-Host

            $root = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify the location of Database? Example format: C:\*'
            $y = read-host -Prompt 'Input file types. Format Example: " .jpg,.mp4,.mp3,.pdf .... " Do * for all'
            $z = Read-Host -Prompt 'Your Save file name will be? Examples: Movies database , Music database , audiobooks.'             
            Get-ChildItem -Path "$root" -Recurse -Include "*$y" | Select Name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$z Andy.csv"
        }
```

You should be able to correct the rest of your script following the "Corrected" example.

**EDIT:**

Credit to TheIncredible1

There are [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) that should never be used other than for their intended purpose. In your case `$Input`:

> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a
>   function. The $input variable is available only to functions and
>   script blocks (which are unnamed functions). In the Process block of a
>   function, the $input variable enumerates the object that is currently
>   in the pipeline. When the Process block completes, there are no
>   objects left in the pipeline, so the $input variable enumerates an
>   empty collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then
>   in the End block, the $input variable enumerates the collection of all
>   input to the function.

However, in this case it should not effect your outcome. But, it is a very bad habit to get into and is best to be avoided.

Comment: You failed to address the most glaring issue which is the use of the variable name `$Input`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 in this case $Input is always 0, correct? Since the function is not parameterized.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I will address the issue with `$Input` being used as a variable. However, this does not effect the current functionality of the script.

Comment: It absolutely affects the script. `$Input` has very special functionality with functions which he is chaining together

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I realize the mistake but do not think it actually breaks anything in this case. `function Show-Menu { $Input }; 1..3 | Show-Menu; function Show-Menu { $Input = 2; $Input; $Input = 3; $Input }; 1..3 | Show-Menu`

Comment: When you manually set it, it is reassigned to a normal variable it seems?

Comment: My point is, you should never use automatic variables (just like you should never use reserved keywords) because the interpreter controls them.  [Here's a convenient list of variables you should never assign things to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: If anything it is a dangerous habit to assign something to  `$Input` as it can give you unexpected results. Seeing he is not enumerating with `$Input` it should not effect this script at all. Here is [another read](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/)